# reactRedux is not defined

Tags: javascript, redux

I am trying to learn Redux (with React).
I don't want to use Node to install dependencies, just doing it manually with script tags.

I am getting the error `reactRedux` is not defined. I thought by adding the `react-redux.js` file I would solve the issue.

Would appreciate any pointers on what I'm doing or understanding wrongly.

(I'm attempting to work through this tutorial https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-a-todo-app-using-react-redux-and-immutable-js/)

Here is the code snippet in question:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="public/js/lib/react.js"></script>
    <script src="public/js/lib/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.5.2/redux.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/4.4.5/react-redux.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/babel">
    const { Map, List } = Immutable;
    const { createStore } = Redux;
    const { Provider, connect } = reactRedux;
```

Comment: Just a tip, you should try use node for this :) Checkout one of the starter kits! https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit

Comment: Thanks, but trying to avoid Node for now ... will get to it in the future

Answer (score 1):

Line 7 from [react-redux.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/4.4.5/react-redux.js) indicates that it should be `ReactRedux` not `reactRedux.`

```
exports["ReactRedux"] = factory(require("react"), require("redux"))
```

So it's just a typo in the tutorial - probably an older version of the library being used when it was written.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capitalize the first r in reactRedux. Change:

```
const { Provider, connect } = reactRedux;
```

To

```
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;
```